# RGB image pixels into its binary representation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, steganography

New to MATLAB and Image processing, I searched but couldn't find the answer

How can I view the binary representation for 24-bit RGB image ( for each channel )

So for example I would like to know that pixel number `x` ( any number ) in the image has

Red 00000001

Blue 01100101

Green 11010101

My intention is to manipulate such values then reconstruct the image

Any guidance/Help would be appreciated

Comment: I suspect that you don't need to convert the numbers at all. You can perform any bit operations on the uint8 without change of representation as in `c = bitxor(img(x,y,1),0x80);`.

Comment: I second what beaker said. What are you exact intentions when you get, for example, 00000001 for Red?

Comment: To check the LSB value and either keep or change it

Comment: Fetch value of lsb (used for extraction): `bitand(value,1)`. Change value of lsb (used for embedding): `bitand(value,254) + bit`, where `bit` is either 1 or 0. It doesn't matter whether the bit already has the same value as the lsb of the pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using `dec2bin`.

```
b = dec2bin(img(1,1),8);
```

For example, if the red, green and blue values of the pixel `img(1,1)` are 255, 223 and 83, you will get

```
11111111
11011101
01010011
```

Where `b(1,:)` is the binary for red (11111111), `b(2,:)` for green (11011101), etc.

---

However, for the intention of changing the value of the lsb, this is not the prefered, or most direct way. Consider using the [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation.

**Embedding** the value of `bit` (can be 0 or 1) in the lsb of `pixel`. `pixel` here refers to one specific value, so only the red, or green, or blue component of a pixel.

```
bitand(pixel,254) + bit;
```

Here, the mask 254 (or 11111110 in binary) zeroes out the lsb of pixel.

```
     11010101    // pixel value
and  11111110    // mask
     11010100    // result

  +         1    // assuming the value of bit is 1
     11010101    // you have now embedded a 1 in the lsb
```

While zeroing out a 1 to then embed a 1 back in it seems superfluous, it's still more direct then checking whether `bit` and the lsb of `pixel` are different and changing them only in that case.

**Extracting** the lsb value of `pixel`

```
bitand(pixel,1);
```

This operation zeroes out all the bits except from the lsb of `pixel`, effectively giving you its value.

```
     11010101    // pixel value; we are interested in the value of the lsb, which is 1
and  00000001    // mask
     00000001    // result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `for`-loop this

```
bitmap = false( [size(img,1), size(img,2), 24] );
for ci=1:3
    for bit=0:7
        bitmap( :,:, (ci-1)*8+bit+1 ) = bitand( img(:,:,ci), uint8(2^bit) );
    end
end
```

Reconstruction is simpler

```
reconstruct = zeros( [size(img,1), size(img,2), 3], 'uint8' );
for ci=1:3
    reconstruct(:,:,ci) = sum( bsxfun(@power, ...
        bitmap(:,:,(ci-1)*8 + (1:8) ),...
        permute( uint8(2.^(7:-1:0)), [1 3 2] ) ), 3 );
end
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, The code seems to work as intended, but im having a hard time understanding the structure.  Does bitmap(1,1,1:8) Represent the value of the red values for the  first pixel?

Comment: `bitmap(1,1,1:8)` are the bits of the red pixel, `bitmap(1,1,9:16)`  of the green, etc. The bits are from the most significant to the least significant, so `bitmap(1,1,8)`, `bitmap(1,1,16)` and `bitmap(1,1,24)` are the least significant bits of the red, green and blue channels respectively.

Comment: Appreciate the help Shai. This question might be unrelated but, is this  the best way to manipulate/Check the lsb for each channel (r,g,b) for every pixel in the image?

Comment: @SeRo no. check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27640832/1714410) I believe you are trying to achive the same goal...